# Any crucial information, about coping partition with installed win7 from hhd to ssd using GParted?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, gparted

I have pretty old windows 7 installation on hdd, i can't install fresh windows on my new ssd, co i need to copy whole partition. I chose GParted to do it. Any crucial information about this? Will i need to do something, beside copying files? I heard about configuring ssd in windows, partition aligned etc. Will i need those, or something else?

Comment: Why can't you fresh install Windows on the new SSD?

Comment: Because i don't have time for this at the moment - to many programs installed, configured, etc.

Comment: Best I could suggest is something like CloneZilla, but I have heard varying reports about partition alignment and don't fully understand the issue, so use at your own risk.